# VS2015 and cordova tools

Tags: cordova

I have a cordova project built in VS2013 update 4 with cordova tools. I just installed vs2015 but it seems I cannot open the project (the project type is not supported by this installation).

I started another new cordova project in VS2015 and I am seeing that folder structure is different then that I had in my previous project.

Is there a way to open the project in vs2015?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but Cordova projects made with 2013 are incompatible with 2015. We changed the project structure based on user feedback. While I know this is an inconvenience, the new project system is a significant improvement.

Sorry for the trouble, but you will need to migrate the project manually if you want to use vs2015.